# MessageHub - api for creating topics?

Tags: ibm-cloud, message-hub

In the bluemix web console, it is possible to create topics.  However, is it possible to create topics using a REST API?  I couldn't see documentation online - maybe I missed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@SHC no worries, it is easy to miss. Try here for a brief mention and link to the Swagger document for the topic administration API: https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/services/MessageHub/messagehub010.html#messagehub037

The docs are currently been restructured to improve discoverability.  Feel free to come back if you have further questions.

Comment: To be compliant with stackoverflow, I'll raise seperate questions.  Many thanks!