# How to get an API key for MessageHub's management rest API?

Tags: ibm-cloud, message-hub

I need to programmmtically create topics - see my other question here: 
[MessageHub - api for creating topics?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40320168/messagehub-api-for-creating-topics)

The MessageHub Management [API](https://github.com/ibm-messaging/message-hub-docs/blob/master/kafka-administration-api/KafkaTopicManagement.yaml) requires an apiKey to interact with it.

How do I generate an API key?  I'm guessing this is a generic bluemix authentication service, but I'm not sure where this resides or how I can interact with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to the Bluemix console and navigate to Message Hub’s Bluemix dashboard by clicking on your service.  Then switch to the “Service Credentials” tab and you should see some json properties as Credentials-1. The 48 character api_key is what you need.

[image: example credentials]

Comment: Thanks again Dominic.  This is useful info, though I would really like to get this information programatically. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40322068/bluemix-cf-api-to-retrieve-the-service-credentials