# Bluemix API to retrieve the service credentials

Tags: ibm-cloud, cloud-foundry, message-hub

In a previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40321385/how-to-get-an-api-key-for-messagehubs-management-rest-api/40321768#40321768), I can get the apiKey for interacting with the MessageHub management api.

I'm not binding to this service to a Bluemix application, so I don't have access to the VCAP_SERVICES environment variable in my application.

I would like to retreive the service credentials programatically.  I think this may be a generic Bluemix cf api question rather than a MessageHub question.

How can I retrieve the service credentials using an API call?

Comment: I think I need this: https://apidocs.cloudfoundry.org/245/service_instances/list_all_service_keys_for_the_service_instance.html.  Testing now ...

Comment: Yep that's correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The https://apidocs.cloudfoundry.org/245/service_instances/list_all_service_keys_for_the_service_instance.html API worked for me.

Using the [cf-python-client](https://github.com/antechrestos/cf-python-client) library:

```
from cloudfoundry_client.client import CloudFoundryClient
target_endpoint = 'https://api.ng.bluemix.net'

client = CloudFoundryClient(target_endpoint, skip_verification=False)
client.init_with_user_credentials(
    ibm_id,
    ibm_id_password
    )

mh_service_instance = client.service_instances.get_first(name='my_service')
if mh_service_instance:
    mh_service_instance_id = mh_service_instance['metadata']['guid']
    print(mh_service_instance_id)
    print(list(mh_service_instance.service_keys()))
```

Answer (score 0):

Sadly because [BlueMix runs a version of Cloud Foundry that is 6 months out of date](http://cf-release-dates.public.providers.cfpush.it/), you can't use the [List Service Keys](https://apidocs.cloudfoundry.org/245/service_instances/list_all_service_keys_for_the_service_instance.html) endpoint.

Your only alternative is to bind it to some app (maybe not even a real app) to extract the credentials.

There is an argument that humans needing the credentials for a service is an anti-pattern, but there are plenty of use cases where it is necessary.

Comment: Maybe this has changed as the list service keys api works for me?